# proteccion contra numeros y letras java

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda estoy aprendiendo java y mi maestra me pide bloquear la entrada de números o letras dependiendo el caso pero me falla mi código me pueden ayudar y me pueden decir formas para mejorar en java o paginas para revisar ?

````
     do      
     {
     columnas1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa las columnas");
     respuesta= validar(columnas1);
     }while(respuesta == true);
     
     do{
     numerovalidar=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese las filas");   
     respuesta = validar(numerovalidar);
     }while(respuesta == true);
     
     
     columnas=Integer.parseInt(columnas1);
     filas=Integer.parseInt(numerovalidar);
     
     int matriz[][] = new int[columnas][filas];
     
     for(int i=0; i<filas;i++ ){
           for(int f=0; f<columnas;f++ ) {
               
               do{
             matriz[i][f]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " matriz["+i+"]["+f+"]:"));
             respuesta = validar(matriz[i][f]); /**AQUI FALLA Y DESDE AQUI DEJA DE COMPILAR 
              *intente convertir matriz[i][f] a string pero si lo hago falla validar pero no se en que*/```
````

Comment: ya probaste a usar try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a suponer que después del do tienes un while y que todo esta cerrado correctamente, podrías enseñar tu o tus métodos validar, ya que debes haber creado un método para pasar por parámetro un string y otro para pasar por parámetro un array, el error puede estar ahí, no puedo decir mucho mas sin ver mas.